# HTML or JavascriptCode to send implicit share intent from Browser

Tags: android, html, android-intent, share

What I would like to do is have html (or JavaScript) code on my page that when triggered will send share intent to android system containing extra information such as text to share. I know this would basicly be implicit intent and will show picker to the user so he/she can chose app(SMS/Twitter/Dropbox all that can handle text sharing) and that is exactly what I want to do.
Is this possible in android?

I know about https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents (Note that it works in other browsers too usually) and it seems promising but in those examples they are using explicit intent instead and there is no example for declaring intent as implicit.

NOTE: I am not looking for how to register my app to handle share intents and know about JScript bridges used with a webview for similar things but those are not what I need. I just want to know how do you send implicit intent using a link in HTML